# Changing picture according to amount of scroll or text id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, scroll

(please no jQuery, only Javascript)

Hi, I'm new to Javascript and I'm wondering if it's possible to make a fixed image which is replaced by another image in the same position during scrolling. That way it will look like the picture is changing while you scroll.

I found one answer which used jQuery and I have no idea what it means since we are not supposed to use that language in class.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-frame-by-frame-moving-image-on-scroll-effect-30ce577c63c2

```
// Global variable to control the scrolling behavior
const step = 30; // For each 30px, change an image
function trackScrollPosition() {
  const y = window.scrollY;
  const label = Math.min(Math.floor(y/30) + 1, 20);
  const imageToUse = fruitImages[label];
  // Change the background image
  $('.image-container').css('background-image', `url('${imageToUse}')`);
}
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $(window).scroll(()=>{
    trackScrollPosition();
  })
})
```

I could understand the tutorial in the link, but this part I don't get at all. Could someone who understands jQuery please translate this to Javascript? It would be the biggest help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Same script in plain JS

```js
// Global variable to control the scrolling behavior
const step = 30; // For each 30px, change an image
function trackScrollPosition() {
  const y = window.scrollY;
  const label = Math.min(Math.floor(y/30) + 1, 20);
  const imageToUse = fruitImages[label];
  // Change the background image
  document.querySelector('.image-container').style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageToUse})`;
}
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll',trackScrollPosition);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.image-container').css('background-image', 'url('${imageToUse}')')` - this part means that we are looking for an element with image-container class and we are changing it's css background-image property to imageToUse (which was previously set to fruitImages[label]).

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $(window).scroll(()=>{
    trackScrollPosition();
  })
})
```

Function above runs once Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate, and is responsible for calling trackScrollPosition function while scrolling.

Comment: This is not what OP asked.